# Material UI List - Separate OnClick for Expand

Tags: reactjs, list, material-ui, nested-lists

I have a `material ui` list that has a nested list. I was wondering if I could have separate `onClick` handlers for when someone clicks anywhere on the list item and for when they specifically click on the expand icon (the upside-down carrot icon on the right side of the list item).

Basically, I want a default procedure to happen when they click anywhere on the list item aside from the carrot icon, and then a separate procedure for when they try to expand the nested list.

Is this possible?

Note: I'm using `ReactJs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the icon click to prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  parentClick = () => {
    console.log('Parent clicked!');
  };
  
  iconClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Icon clicked!');
  };
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="item" onClick={this.parentClick}>
        <span>Really long text to take up some room in the item.</span>
        <span onClick={this.iconClick}>Icon</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.item {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ededed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```